# Got issue from running "jpm sign" command

Tags: firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I have tried to use "jpm sign" command to signing the Firefox extension. But I got an issue regard to version number does not match install.rdf file.

> JPM [info] Signing XPI:
>
> JPM [error] Server response: Version does not match install.rdf. ( status: 400 )
>
> JPM [info] FAIL

I have tried by changing the em:version, em:minVersion, em:maxVersion but still getting same error.
If anyone know the root cause of this issue the please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `jpm sign` [expects](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/blob/6eec5221c3801be26577e635fdcea098b300de66/lib/sign.js#L98) that a `package.json` is [available](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/blob/6eec5221c3801be26577e635fdcea098b300de66/lib/utils.js#L144) in your `xpi` file.

Make sure that is, and [contains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) identical `id` and `version` fields as in the `install.rdf` which is what is actually looked at on AMO servers.

An [issue](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/issues/450) was already reported. Simply put, jpm does not actually parse `install.rdf` but rather uses `package.json` directly which fails silently if it does not exist and causes the issue you are seeing. There is a proposed [patch](https://github.com/mozilla-jetpack/jpm/pull/456) to 'fix' this by providing a better error message.